# CREATE EXTENSION postgis fails,

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am on `Ubuntu 18.04` with the `psql (PostgreSQL) 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1)`

Running `temba=# create extension postgis;` fails with the following error

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

I ran `find /usr -name postgis.control` only to find out `postgis.control` is inside a folder named `12` instead of `10`

```
laptop@xyz-x:~$ find /usr -name postgis.control
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis.control
```

**Edit 1**

I have already ran `sudo apt-get install postgis`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
postgis is already the newest version (3.0.1+dfsg-2.pgdg18.04+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ran this `sudo apt install postgis postgresql-10-postgis-2.5` and it worked

Comment: The Ubuntu software database thru 19.10 is Postgres v10. That's why you apt-get created into a folder /10/ instead of /12/.  Ubuntu 20.04 is supposed to go with Postgres v12. However Postgis 2.5 is (at least should be) compatable with Postgres 10 and 12. So maybe just copy /10/ to /12/ any retry to create extession.

Answer (score 11):

I was not sure what version of postgres or postgis I needed, so I found `sudo apt install postgis postgresql-postgis` worked.

It either gave me the latest, or matched my installed postgres version.

---

Answer (score 3):

I use Linux Mint and had this problem for postgres10, and also: `could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.4": No such file or directory` following that. Installation of specific extension **and** scripts package cures it for me:

`sudo apt install postgresql-10-postgis-2.4 postgresql-10-postgis-2.4-scripts Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done postgresql-10-postgis-2.4-scripts is already the newest version (2.4.3+dfsg-4). postgresql-10-postgis-2.4-scripts set to manually installed. The following NEW packages will be installed libprotobuf-c1 postgresql-10-postgis-2.4`

Then go, in my case to pgAdmin and `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` returns successfully.

Comment: Funny that Synaptic says the script can be safely removed. Apparently it still has use.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt install postgis postgresql-13-postgis-3` for postgres 13.1 and next `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` (postgres command)

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the file location where postgis is installed;

   *C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin*
2. Run [stackbuilder.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSQFQ.png);
3. Select connected your database;
4. Select "Spatial Extensions" and install

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, and easier, run `sudo apt install postgis postgresql-12-postgis-2.5` for postgres12

Answer (score 0):

If CREATE EXTENSION postgis is not working and giving you the error no such file or directory.then do follow the following steps:

Go to the file location where postgis is installed;

1.C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin
2.Run stackbuilder.exe;
3.Select connected your database;
4.Select "Spatial Extensions" and install

and if you are stackbuilder is not responding wait for some time try with fast internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL 14: `sudo apt install postgis postgresql-14-postgis-3`
Tested on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

For RedHat/CentOs/Fedora this issue can be resolved by

`yum install postgresql13-contrib`

Reference: https://github.com/hapostgres/pg_auto_failover/issues/558